# How do I convert factorial variables into presence-absence data in r?

Tags: r

I've got a dataset with an abundance variable where the data is ordinal (0, 1-5, 6-10, 10+) but I need to convert it into presence/ absence data (0 or 1). How do I go about doing this?

Here is the data:

```r
'data.frame':   100 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ date    : Date, format: "2021-02-11" "2021-02-15" "2021-02-16" "2021-02-15" ...
 $ abund   : Factor w/ 4 levels "0","1-5","6-10",..: 4 1 3 3 4 1 4 2 1 3 ...
 $ postcode: chr  "EH12 7ET" "NW1 1HP" "TA21 0AS" "LE7 3SY" ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
your_data$abund <- ifelse(your_data$abund=="0",0,1)
```

or

```
your_data$abund <- as.numeric(your_data$abund!="0")
```

The latter works because `as.numeric()` converts `FALSE` to 0 and `TRUE` to 1.

or use `transform(your_data, abund=...)` (base R) or `your_data %>% mutate(across(abund,~1-as.numeric(.=="0))` or ...